# Getting all the value from a JsLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> in flutter

Tags: flutter

Writing an app that might have data update, how could I update JsLinkedHashMap<String,dynamic>  value,here is the sample code

```
List samplelist = [{"name":'abc',"letter1":'a',"letter2":'b'}];
```

Here is a new item named
`var string = {'letter3':'c','letter4':'d'};`
How could I add it in the JsLinkedHashMap with name = abc and after "letter2"?

Answer (score 0):

you do it like this:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> samplelist = [{"name": 'abc', "letter1": 'a', "letter2": 'b'}];

Map<String, dynamic> string = {'letter3': 'c', 'letter4': 'd'};

samplelist[0].addAll(string);
```

> Output

```
[{name: abc, letter1: a, letter2: b, letter3: c, letter4: d}]
```

Comment: Thank you but how could I ensure that those data add under"name":"abc"?

Comment: if the name is going to be added to the list before anything then there is no need to check anything. If you are not sure then you have to manually sort the sampleList first before adding any data to it.